# Autocomplete query using Firebase. Ordered By key (iOS)

Tags: ios, autocomplete, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to query a list of food items from my Firebase database. The app has a UITextfield where the user can type the search word for the food item. I have already implemented basic code for this to work using the below code.

```
NSString *searchString = [sender.text lowercaseString];

[[[[[self.ref queryOrderedByChild:@"fuudTitleCapped"] queryLimitedToLast:5] queryStartingAtValue:searchString] queryEndingAtValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\uf8ff",searchString]] observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@ Key %@ Value", snapshot.key,snapshot.value);
}];
```

My database is structured like this

```
{
"fuuds": {
    "-KMT1MHSrR-n6TN9K_wR": {
        "fuudDescription": "Dummy discrp",
        "fuudImage": "Dummy image",
        "fuudLatitude": "Dummy lat",
        "fuudPrice": 154,
        "fuudRating": "54",
        "fuudRestaurent": "Dummy rest",
        "fuudTitle": "Dummy title",
        "fuudTitleCapped": "Dummy title"
    },
    "-KMT1MHVAo0OxMkKBktB": {
        "fuudDescription": "Dummy discrip",
        "fuudImage": "Dummy image",
        "fuudLatitude": "Dummy lat",
        "fuudPrice": 46,
        "fuudRating": "7854",
        "fuudRestaurent": "Dummy rest",
        "fuudTitle": "Dummy title",
        "fuudTitleCapped": "Dummy title"
    }
}
}
```

What I want is to order the results by the key "fuudPrice".

Can anybody suggest me a way to do this??

Comment: Is your "self.ref" reference pointing to the "fuuds" node?

Comment: Yes.    
self.ref = [[[FIRDatabase database] reference] child:@"fuuds"];

Comment: I would recommend against this in general. Querying Firebase as the user types is going to cause issues; for example. The user wants to type the word Hello. They Type H (firebase query) e (another query) and then Firebase returns the query from the H. That internet lag can make it frustrating for the user. You will be way better off loading the query able data from firebase up-front (in an array for example) and then filter that array while the user types.

Comment: The "fuuds" node can contain thousands of objects. Maybe even more. So I don't want to load all of them at once. I want only the once the user type.